# Creating a file type with new icon

Tags: ico

I have a text based file i have given an extension named .val i have also changed its icon by selecting Computer>Open tools>Open folder options>

however though this changes the icon for the extension it only changes it on my computer, I would like to know how I can do this for all machines. even if that means building somthing that needs to be installed, which is fine with me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a little program awhile ago. The windows registry thing is a mess. Save yourself a lot of time and use this installer package - it has a wizard that will create an install script for you. Navigate to your program, icon, etc. Pretty easy.

http://hmne.sourceforge.net/

As I recall, in windows icons are set based on what program is opening it, so indirectly the file type. So first you have to create reg entries for your application on your computer. Then you have to associate that file type with your extension. And then the extension gets the icon from your app settings. This of course is different in WinXP vs. Win7. Thus why I think you should avoid a lot of headache and use an installer.

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Your App\DefaultIcon]
```